# WebRTC screen sharing broken on Debian under Wayland + Gnome + Pulseaudio

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, wayland, pipewire

I cannot screen share on Debian 11 (bullseye) on any web app running in Brave, Google Chrome or Firefox.
From [this WebRTC experiment](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing), I can click "Screen share" and get the dialogue where I can either choose a window or the entire screen. In both cases, clicking "Share" makes the UI slide back to "Chrome tab sharing" and the logs show:

```
xdg-desktop-por: Unhandled parent window type 
xdg-desktop-por: Failed to associate portal window with parent window 
xdg-desktop-por: Failed to start session: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: Failed to start screen cast: Couldn't connect pipewire context
brave-browser.desktop: [7627:7627:0410/165213.470354:ERROR:screencast_portal.cc(365)] Failed to start the screen cast session.
brave-browser.desktop: [7627:7627:0410/165213.470366:ERROR:base_capturer_pipewire.cc(81)] ScreenCastPortal failed: 3
```

Pipewire is not my audio engine (as confirmed with `$ pactl info`), so I don't know why it's trying to use it, but since I already have some bullseye-backports package I figured I'd try upgrading with pipewire from backports, + xdg-desktop-portal{,-gtk}, and still no luck.

I get the same results when changing `chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer` to "Enabled" and/or setting `chrome://flags/#ozone-platform-hint` to "Wayland".
Below are my installed pipewire-* packages:

```
gstreamer1.0-pipewire/bullseye-backports,now 0.3.65-2~bpo11+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpipewire-0.3-0/bullseye-backports,now 0.3.65-2~bpo11+1 amd64 [installed]
libpipewire-0.3-common/bullseye-backports,bullseye-backports,now 0.3.65-2~bpo11+1 all [installed,automatic]
libpipewire-0.3-modules/bullseye-backports,now 0.3.65-2~bpo11+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
pipewire-alsa/bullseye-backports,now 0.3.65-2~bpo11+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
pipewire-audio-client-libraries/bullseye-backports,bullseye-backports,now 0.3.65-2~bpo11+1 all [installed]
pipewire-bin/bullseye-backports,now 0.3.65-2~bpo11+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
pipewire-jack/bullseye-backports,now 0.3.65-2~bpo11+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
pipewire-pulse/bullseye-backports,now 0.3.65-2~bpo11+1 amd64 [installed]
pipewire/bullseye-backports,now 0.3.65-2~bpo11+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libwireplumber-0.4-0/bullseye-backports,now 0.4.13-1~bpo11+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
wireplumber/bullseye-backports,now 0.4.13-1~bpo11+1 amd64 [installed]
```

For what it's worth I can start `pipewire` in a terminal and try to screen share and the behaviour changes slightly: I have a grey box where the monitor would be mirrored in the "Share" dialogue, I can start sharing but it'll effectively share nothing, logs are the same but the line "Couldn't connect pipewire context" is no longer.